# Asp.net using entity framework to run join statement and display in GridView

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, gridview

`Schedule` table:

```
ScheduleId(PK), AirplaneId(FK), OriginId(FK), Duration-String
```

`Airplane` table:

```
AirplaneId(PK), PlaneCode-String
```

`Origin` table:

```
OriginId(PK), OriginName-String
```

I wanted to display something like:

```
ScheduleId | PlaneCode | OriginName | Duration
```

**Schedule.vb**

```
Public Class Schedule
Public Property ID As Int32
Public Property Duration As String

'Foreign key of airplane_Id
Public Overridable Property Airplane As Airplane
'Foreign key of origin_Id
Public Overridable Property Origin As Origin  
End Class
```

**Airplane.vb**

```
Public Class Airplane
Public Property ID As Int32
Public Property PlaneCode As String
End Class
```

**Origin.vb**

```
Public Class Origin
Public Property ID As Int32
Public Property OriginName As String
End Class
```

My grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearchFlight" runat="server" ItemType="CIM.Schedule" SelectMethod="gvSearchFlight_GetData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None">
```

GridView's `SelectMethod`:

```
Dim dbContext As New ApplicationDbContext

    Public Function gvSearchFlight_GetData() As IQueryable(Of Schedule)
    Dim schedules = (From sche In dbContext.Schedule
                     Join air In dbContext.Airplane
                    On sche.Airplane.ID Equals air.ID).ToList()
    Return schedules
End Function
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VB$AnonymousType_11`2[CIM.Schedule,CIM.Airplane]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CIM.Schedule]'

**Edit**: I don't really know how to write the "Select New" statement..

```
Public Class ScheduleInformation
Public Property Schedule As Schedule
Public Property Airplane As Airplane
Public Property Origin As Origin
End Class
```

```
    Public Function gvSearchFlight_GetData() As IQueryable(Of ScheduleInformation)
    Dim schedules = (From sche In dbContext.Schedule
                     Join air In dbContext.Airplane On sche.Airplane.ID Equals air.ID
                     Join ori In dbContext.Origin On sche.Origin.ID Equals ori.ID
                     Select New ScheduleInformation())
    Return schedules
End Function
```

Comment: That is to be expected. Your query is returning items that are instances of an undeclared type that contains the joined `Schedule` and `Airplane` objects but you're trying to put them somewhere that `Schedule` objects are expected. You would need to declare your own type that has properties for the data from both the source types, specify that as the item type for the grid and then have your LINQ query map to that type.

Comment: May I know how to do so?? The part on "declare your own type", and "LINQ query map to that type". Please any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already know how to define a type because your first three code snippets do just that. As far as mapping is concerned, that's simply assigning data from one type to another. In your case, you would need to add a `Select` clause to your query that creates a new instance of your type and then maps from the two source objects, i.e. the `Schedule` and the `Airplane` to that instance. Your query, and thus your method, will then return a list of that type.

Comment: So what you meant is I could do something like this?
ScheduleInformation table
Public Class ScheduleInformation
  Public Property Schedule As Schedule
  Public Property Airplane As Airplane
  Public Property Origin As Origin
End Class

Comment: I've never used a `GridView` so I don't know exactly how it works but I'm not sure that that will help because the items in your `GridView` will then have properties of types `Schedule`, `Airplane` and `Origin` rather than the `Strings` within those objects that you actually want to display. If you can specify a navigation path for a column, e.g. `Schedule.Duration`, then you're OK but, otherwise, you need to change that custom type to have the properties you actually want to display, i.e. the same ones as the other types have but combined.

Comment: *"I don't really know how to write the "Select New" statement"*. You need to either add a constructor to your type with appropriate parameters or else you need to use an object initializer to set appropriate properties. Research that term to find out what it means. It exists specifically for this scenario.

Comment: Ohh I solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve my problem.

**ScheduleInformation.vb**

```
Public Class ScheduleInformation
  Public Property Schedule As Schedule
  Public Property Airplane As Airplane
  Public Property Origin As Origin
End Class
```

**GridView's SelectMethod**

```
'GridView's SelectMethod to get data
Public Function gvSearchFlight_GetData() As IQueryable(Of ScheduleInformation)
    Dim schedules = (From sche In dbContext.Schedule
                 Join air In dbContext.Airplane On sche.Airplane.ID Equals air.ID
                 Join ori In dbContext.Origin On sche.Origin.ID Equals ori.ID
                 Select New ScheduleInformation With {.Schedule = sche, .Airplane = air, .Origin = ori})
    Return schedules
End Function
```

Then, in my  tag, I wrote as such:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearchFlight" runat="server" ItemType="CIM.ScheduleInformation" SelectMethod="gvSearchFlight_GetData" AutoGenerateColumns="false">...
```